# Java jdbc handle close connection

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, try-catch

I have two question for my problem .

1.Is it necessary to include a catch block in my method if I have a throw?

2.Is it necessary to try - finally block in my method to handle connection.close?

```
public int count() throws SQLException {
    XAConnection xaConnection=null;
    Statement statement=null;
    ResultSet resultSet=null;
    int count  =0;
    try{
      String SQL = "SELECT count(*) FROM book";
      xaConnection = dbService.getConnection();
      statement = xaConnection.getConnection().createStatement();
      resultSet = statement.executeQuery(SQL);
      if(resultSet.next()){
        count = resultSet.getInt(1);
      }
    }
    finally {
      if(xaConnection!= null){
        xaConnection.close();
      }
      if(resultSet != null){
        resultSet.close();
      }
      if(statement != null){
        statement.close();
      }
    }
    return  count;
  }
```

Comment: [Try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) syntax is your friend.

Answer (score 2):

> *1. Is it necessary to include a catch block in my method if I have a throw?*

No, it's fine to do try-finally. Allowed combinations include try-catch, try-finally, and try-catch-finally.

There's also an option called "try with resources" which *looks* like a standalone "try" but behind the scenes it behaves like try-finally. There are some examples in the Java Language Spec [section 14.20.3.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se18/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3.1).

> *2. Is it necessary to try - finally block in my method to handle connection.close?*

No, it isn't strictly necessary – Java will allow you to do it. However, opening connections without closing them will lead to problems over time, so yes you should close them.

---

Here's an edit to your posted code showing how you could clean things up by using try-with-resources.

- There's an outer try-finally where `xaConnection` is closed – it isn't possible to do try-with on [`javax.sql.XAConnection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sql/XAConnection.html) because it doesn't implement [`java.lang.AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html).
- Statement and ResultSet both work with AutoCloseable, so they're inside try-with-resources blocks.
- Removed the "count" variable – if you find a value in the result set, just return it; otherwise return 0 (like you were doing)

```
import javax.sql.XAConnection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public int count() throws SQLException {
    String SQL = "SELECT count(*) FROM book";
    XAConnection xaConnection = dbService.getConnection();
    try {
        try (Statement statement = xaConnection.getConnection().createStatement()) {
            try (ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(SQL)) {
                if (resultSet.next()) {
                    return resultSet.getInt(1);
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;
    } finally {
        if (xaConnection != null) {
            xaConnection.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The second question I mean, the close() method must be put in the finally block or not in finally?

Comment: If you intend the use `close()` method, then yes it should go inside the "finally" block. If it outside the finally block, there are paths through the code where it will skip calling "close()". For example: 1. open connection, 2. start "try" block, 3. inside try, an exception is thrown (something went wrong), 4. "finally" code block runs, but "close()" is not there (it's instead outside of "finally"), 5. the exception (from 3) has to be thrown to caller, so remaining code in your method would be skipped, and your outsite-the-finally-block call to "close()" would never run.